# Unable to playback captured audio using USB sound card

Tags: audio, alsa, usb-device, usb-audio

I am trying to capture and play audio using C program. For this I [got this tutorial.](https://jan.newmarch.name/LinuxSound/Sampled/Alsa/). Here is the program which I am running:-

```
/**
 * Jan Newmarch
 */

#define PERIOD_SIZE 1024
#define BUF_SIZE (PERIOD_SIZE * 2)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

void print_pcm_state(snd_pcm_t *handle, char *name) {
  switch (snd_pcm_state(handle)) {
  case SND_PCM_STATE_OPEN:
    printf("state open %s\n", name);
    break;

  case SND_PCM_STATE_SETUP:
    printf("state setup %s\n", name);
    break;

  case SND_PCM_STATE_PREPARED:
    printf("state prepare %s\n", name);
    break;

  case SND_PCM_STATE_RUNNING:
    printf("state running %s\n", name);
    break;

  case SND_PCM_STATE_XRUN:
    printf("state xrun %s\n", name);
    break;

  default:
    printf("state other %s\n", name);
    break;

  }
}


int setparams(snd_pcm_t *handle, char *name) {
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t *hw_params;
  int err;


  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc (&hw_params)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot allocate hardware parameter structure (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_any (handle, hw_params)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot initialize hardware parameter structure (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access (handle, hw_params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot set access type (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format (handle, hw_params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot set sample format (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  unsigned int rate = 48000;    
  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near (handle, hw_params, &rate, 0)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot set sample rate (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }
  printf("Rate for %s is %d\n", name, rate);

  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels (handle, hw_params, 2)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot set channel count (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  snd_pcm_uframes_t buffersize = BUF_SIZE;
  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size_near(handle, hw_params, &buffersize)) < 0) {
    printf("Unable to set buffer size %li: %s\n", BUF_SIZE, snd_strerror(err));
    exit (1);;
  }

  snd_pcm_uframes_t periodsize = PERIOD_SIZE;
  fprintf(stderr, "period size now %d\n", periodsize);
  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle, hw_params, &periodsize, 0)) < 0) {
    printf("Unable to set period size %li: %s\n", periodsize, snd_strerror(err));
    exit (1);
  }

  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params (handle, hw_params)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot set parameters (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  snd_pcm_uframes_t p_psize;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(hw_params, &p_psize, NULL);
  fprintf(stderr, "period size %d\n", p_psize);

  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size(hw_params, &p_psize);
  fprintf(stderr, "buffer size %d\n", p_psize);

  snd_pcm_hw_params_free (hw_params);

  if ((err = snd_pcm_prepare (handle)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot prepare audio interface for use (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  return 0;
}

int set_sw_params(snd_pcm_t *handle, char *name) {
  snd_pcm_sw_params_t *swparams;
  int err;

  snd_pcm_sw_params_alloca(&swparams);

  err = snd_pcm_sw_params_current(handle, swparams);
  if (err < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Broken configuration for this PCM: no configurations available\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  err = snd_pcm_sw_params_set_start_threshold(handle, swparams, PERIOD_SIZE);
  if (err < 0) {
    printf("Unable to set start threshold: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    return err;
  }
  err = snd_pcm_sw_params_set_avail_min(handle, swparams, PERIOD_SIZE);
  if (err < 0) {
    printf("Unable to set avail min: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    return err;
  }

  if (snd_pcm_sw_params(handle, swparams) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to install sw params:\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  return 0;
}

/************** some code from latency.c *****************/

main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  int err;
  int buf[BUF_SIZE];
  snd_pcm_t *playback_handle;
  snd_pcm_t *capture_handle;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t *hw_params;
  FILE *fin;
  size_t nread;
  snd_pcm_format_t format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE;
  if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s in-card out-card\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  } 

  /**** Out card *******/
  if ((err = snd_pcm_open (&playback_handle, argv[2], SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot open audio device %s (%s)\n", 
         argv[2],
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  setparams(playback_handle, "playback");
  set_sw_params(playback_handle, "playback");


  /*********** In card **********/

  if ((err = snd_pcm_open (&capture_handle, argv[1], SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot open audio device %s (%s)\n", 
         argv[1],
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  setparams(capture_handle, "capture");
  set_sw_params(capture_handle, "capture");

  if ((err = snd_pcm_link(capture_handle, playback_handle)) < 0) {
    printf("Streams link error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    exit(0);
  }

  if ((err = snd_pcm_prepare (playback_handle)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot prepare playback audio interface for use (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  /**************** stuff something into the playback buffer ****************/
  if (snd_pcm_format_set_silence(format, buf, 2*BUF_SIZE) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "silence error\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  int n = 0;
  while (n++ < 2) {
    if (snd_pcm_writei (playback_handle, buf, BUF_SIZE) < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "write error\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  /************* COPY ************/
  while (1) {
    int nread;
    if ((nread = snd_pcm_readi (capture_handle, buf, BUF_SIZE)) != BUF_SIZE) {
      if (nread < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "read from audio interface failed (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (nread));
      } else {
    fprintf (stderr, "read from audio interface failed after %d frames\n", nread);
      } 
      snd_pcm_prepare(capture_handle);
      continue;
    }

    if ((err = snd_pcm_writei (playback_handle, buf, nread)) != nread) {
      if (err < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "write to audio interface failed (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
      } else {
    fprintf (stderr, "write to audio interface failed after %d frames\n", err);
      }
      snd_pcm_prepare(playback_handle);
    }
  }


  snd_pcm_drain(playback_handle);   
  snd_pcm_close (playback_handle);
  exit (0);
}
```

I compile it and run with following arguments:-

```
./playback-capture hw:0 hw:0
```

Till now my code is running fine, but now I decide to run this program using USB sound card. For this I edit

> /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

Here are the changes :-

I replace

```
options snd_usb_audio index=-2
options snd_hda_intel index=-1
```

with

```
options snd_usb_audio index=-1
options snd_hda_intel index=-2
```

And I replace

```
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-1
```

with

```
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-1
```

Now, when i run my code , I got this output:-

```
Rate for playback is 48000
period size now 1024
period size 1024
buffer size 2048
Rate for capture is 48000
cannot set channel count (Invalid argument)
```

So, can anyone tell me what else should I do to run my code using sound card.

Note:- I run command

```
aplay -l
```

and got this output:-

```
card 0: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC221 Analog [ALC221 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Apparently, your device does not support two channels. Try `plughw` instead of `hw`.

Comment: I tried this command './playback-capture plughw:0 plughw:0' and get this output:-
ALSA lib pcm_hw.c:1667:(_snd_pcm_hw_open) Invalid value for card
cannot open audio device plughw:0 (No such file or directory)

Comment: @tabish run with sudo: `sudo './playback-capture plughw:0 plughw:0`

Answer (score 0):

As a part of a project I want to have a Full Duplex
ALSA [Advance Linux Sound Architecture](https://www.alsa-project.org/) example that can :

1. Capture sound from a sound card thru microphone jack (pink).
2. Play on other USB sound card output (Line-out green jack).

---

By performing some little change on your Code here is the two-way ALSA Capture-play example.

---

***Code***

```
/**
 * Jan Newmarch
 */
 
 
/*
 * File name: rec-play-inline.c
 * 
 * compile: gcc rec-play-inline.c -o rec-play-inline -lasound
 * 
 * run: ./rec-play-inline "plughw:2,0" "plughw:0,0"
 * 
 * 
 * */
  

#define PERIOD_SIZE 1024
#define BUF_SIZE (PERIOD_SIZE * 2)

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>

void print_pcm_state(snd_pcm_t *handle, char *name) {
  switch (snd_pcm_state(handle)) {
  case SND_PCM_STATE_OPEN:
    printf("state open %s\n", name);
    break;

  case SND_PCM_STATE_SETUP:
    printf("state setup %s\n", name);
    break;

  case SND_PCM_STATE_PREPARED:
    printf("state prepare %s\n", name);
    break;

  case SND_PCM_STATE_RUNNING:
    printf("state running %s\n", name);
    break;

  case SND_PCM_STATE_XRUN:
    printf("state xrun %s\n", name);
    break;

  default:
    printf("state other %s\n", name);
    break;

  }
}


int setparams(snd_pcm_t *handle, char *name) {
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t *hw_params;
  int err;


  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_malloc (&hw_params)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot allocate hardware parameter structure (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_any (handle, hw_params)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot initialize hardware parameter structure (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access (handle, hw_params, SND_PCM_ACCESS_RW_INTERLEAVED)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot set access type (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format (handle, hw_params, SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot set sample format (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  unsigned int rate = 48000;    
  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near (handle, hw_params, &rate, 0)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot set sample rate (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }
  printf("Rate for %s is %d\n", name, rate);

  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels (handle, hw_params, 2)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot set channel count (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  snd_pcm_uframes_t buffersize = BUF_SIZE;
  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_size_near(handle, hw_params, &buffersize)) < 0) {
    printf("Unable to set buffer size %li: %s\n", (long int)BUF_SIZE, snd_strerror(err));
    exit (1);;
  }

  snd_pcm_uframes_t periodsize = PERIOD_SIZE;
  fprintf(stderr, "period size now %d\n", (int) periodsize);
  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near(handle, hw_params, &periodsize, 0)) < 0) {
    printf("Unable to set period size %li: %s\n", periodsize, snd_strerror(err));
    exit (1);
  }

  if ((err = snd_pcm_hw_params (handle, hw_params)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot set parameters (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  snd_pcm_uframes_t p_psize;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_period_size(hw_params, &p_psize, NULL);
  fprintf(stderr, "period size %d\n", (int)p_psize);

  snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_size(hw_params, &p_psize);
  fprintf(stderr, "buffer size %d\n", (int)p_psize);

  snd_pcm_hw_params_free (hw_params);

  if ((err = snd_pcm_prepare (handle)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot prepare audio interface for use (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  return 0;
}

int set_sw_params(snd_pcm_t *handle, char *name) {
  snd_pcm_sw_params_t *swparams;
  int err;

  snd_pcm_sw_params_alloca(&swparams);

  err = snd_pcm_sw_params_current(handle, swparams);
  if (err < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Broken configuration for this PCM: no configurations available\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  err = snd_pcm_sw_params_set_start_threshold(handle, swparams, PERIOD_SIZE);
  if (err < 0) {
    printf("Unable to set start threshold: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    return err;
  }
  err = snd_pcm_sw_params_set_avail_min(handle, swparams, PERIOD_SIZE);
  if (err < 0) {
    printf("Unable to set avail min: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    return err;
  }

  if (snd_pcm_sw_params(handle, swparams) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "unable to install sw params:\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  return 0;
}

/************** some code from latency.c *****************/

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i;
  int err;
  int buf[BUF_SIZE];
  snd_pcm_t *playback_handle;
  snd_pcm_t *capture_handle;
  snd_pcm_hw_params_t *hw_params;
  FILE *fin;
  size_t nread;
  snd_pcm_format_t format = SND_PCM_FORMAT_S16_LE;
  
  ///Check for command line arguments
  if (argc != 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s input-soundCard  output-soundCard\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
  } 
  
  
  /**** Out card *******/
  if ((err = snd_pcm_open (&playback_handle, argv[1], SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot open audio device %s (%s)\n", 
         argv[2],
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  setparams(playback_handle, "playback");
  set_sw_params(playback_handle, "playback");


  /*********** In card **********/

  if ((err = snd_pcm_open (&capture_handle, argv[2], SND_PCM_STREAM_CAPTURE, 0)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot open audio device %s (%s)\n", 
         argv[1],
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  setparams(capture_handle, "capture");
  set_sw_params(capture_handle, "capture");
  
  
  ///Comment by EE
/*
  if ((err = snd_pcm_link(capture_handle, playback_handle)) < 0) {
    printf("Streams link error: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    exit(0);
  }
*/


  if ((err = snd_pcm_prepare (playback_handle)) < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "cannot prepare playback audio interface for use (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
    exit (1);
  }

  /**************** stuff something into the playback buffer ****************/
  if (snd_pcm_format_set_silence(format, buf, 2*BUF_SIZE) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "silence error\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  
  
  ///Comment by EE
/*
  int n = 0;
  while (n++ < 2) {
    if (snd_pcm_writei (playback_handle, buf, BUF_SIZE) < 0) {
      fprintf(stderr, "write error\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }
*/
///



  /************* Capture and Play Voice ***************/
  
  while (1) {
    int nread;
    if ((nread = snd_pcm_readi (capture_handle, buf, BUF_SIZE)) != BUF_SIZE) {
      if (nread < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "read from audio interface failed (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (nread));
      } else {
    fprintf (stderr, "read from audio interface failed after %d frames\n", nread);
      } 
      snd_pcm_prepare(capture_handle);
      continue;
    }
    
    ///added by EE
    snd_pcm_prepare(playback_handle);
    ///
    
    if ((err = snd_pcm_writei (playback_handle, buf, nread)) != nread) {
      if (err < 0) {
    fprintf (stderr, "write to audio interface failed (%s)\n",
         snd_strerror (err));
      } else {
    fprintf (stderr, "write to audio interface failed after %d frames\n", err);
      }
      snd_pcm_prepare(playback_handle);
    }
  }


  snd_pcm_drain(playback_handle);   
  snd_pcm_close (playback_handle);
  exit (0);
  
  return 0;
}
```

---

## Explanation

My onboard sound card is : `plughw:0,0` and USB attached external sound card is: `plughw:2,0`

I found out these name by running following commands:

- To have a list of play devices:`aplay --list--devices`
- To have a list of capture devices:`arecord --list-devices`

---

## Source

By adding `snd_pcm_prepare(playback_handle);` before  call `writei()` resolve issue from
[ALSA: buffer underrun on snd_pcm_writei call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23092895/alsa-buffer-underrun-on-snd-pcm-writei-call)